# Escape special character in a command's argument

Tags: bash

I'm using the below command in a script:

```
ssh user@<ip> "ssh user1@<ip1> 'df -k /local/ | awk '{print \$4}' | tail -1'"
```

so it escapes once the special character '$' but it sends the command as below in the second server:

```
debug1: Sending command: df -k /local/ | awk {print } | tail -1
awk: cmd. line:1: {print
awk: cmd. line:1:       ^ unexpected newline or end of string
```

can someone help me with a solution?

Comment: Is there some authentication for the second server??

Comment: no authentication. keys exchanged.

Comment: Look into using `ssh`'s ProxyCommand option, so that you can connect "directly" to <ip1> from your local host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for the exterior quotes in this particular case, actually.

```
ssh user@<ip> ssh user1@<ip1> "df -k /local/ | awk '{print \$4}' | tail -1"
```

But there is also no reason to run the postprocessing on the remote host.

```
ssh user@<ip> ssh user1@<ip1> df -k /local/ | awk '{print $4}' | tail -1
```

You can also optimize out the `tail`:

```
ssh user@<ip> ssh user1@<ip1> df -k /local/ | awk '{x=$4}END{print x}'
```

In the general case, if you need to mix both double and single quotes, you can backslash-escape double quotes inside double quotes, but single quotes inside single quotes are not possible.

```
ssh user@<ip> "ssh user1@<ip1> \"df -k /local/ | awk '{x=\$4}END{print x}'\""
```

Answer (score 1):

Here document would be usefull

```
ssh user@<ip> <<EOIP
ssh user1@<ip1> <<EOIP1
df -k /local/ | awk '{print \$4}' | tail -1
EOIP1
EOIP
```

If the second server asks for a password, then this wont work, instead use `sshpass` to provide the password as

```
ssh user@<ip> <<EOIP
sshpass -p password ssh user1@<ip1> <<EOIP1
df -k /local/ | awk '{print \$4}' | tail -1
EOIP1
EOIP
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this command with escaped quotes:

```
ssh user@<ip> "ssh user1@<ip1> \"df -k /local/ | awk '{print \$4}' | tail -1\""
```